# What is the fastest way to filter documents by flags?

Tags: elasticsearch

Documents in my index can have different flags for pre-filtering, e.g. `INVALID`, `PRIVATE`, etc. Every flag covers a different aspect of the document, so they are not related to each other, i.e. they're actually Boolean values.

**Goal:** Find the fastest way to filter these documents before running a scored query.

**Options:**

- Create a field for each flag as `Boolean Field`, so they can be filtered via true or false
- Create a field for each flag as `Keyword Field`, so they can be filtered via an `Exists Query` if the entry has a value or is NULL.
- Create ONE field for ALL flags as `Text Field`, so they can be filtered via a regular `Match Query`
- Any other method I didn't think of.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Clearly the first option

Comment: @Val I tested this... and you're correct. Thanks. See answer below.

Comment: Nice job, thanks for sharing your findings!

Answer (score 1):

So, I tested this and got to the following results:

**TL;DR:** Use Boolean Fields for flags if you need to query for multiple flags at once. If you have to query for only one flag value, then use whatever you like.

---

Documents in index: 10.000.000

**Fields for flags:**

- `nullFlag`, possible values: `null` or `"exists"`, query: `Exists Query`
- `booleanFlag`, possible values: `true` or `false`, query: `Term Query`
- `textFlag`, possible values: `VALID`, `INVALID`, `DUMMY_FLAG1`, `DUMMY_FLAG2` or `DUMMY_FLAG3`, query: `Match Query`

**Notes:**

- All flags for testing are spread evenly, ~50/50. The "dummy flags" always occur to make the field more "realistic".
- Node Query Cache was disabled via `index.queries.cache.enabled: false`.
- First run could be slower due to JVM startup.  I verified that the Query Cache is disabled.
- The queries are as provided by the native Java QueryBuilder, ignore the `adjust_pure_negative` and `boost`.
- I have no idea if the queries are optimal or even correct.

**Results:**

- `Exists Query` seems to be the slowest
- Filtering for Boolean values via `Term Query` and checking for text flags via `Match Query` don't seem to differ, **IF** you only filter for one flag.
- If you're filtering for multiple flags, then Boolean values via `Term Query` are faster.
- I have no idea if the queries are optimal or even correct.

**Tests:**

### booleanFlag - Term Query

Query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "booleanFlag" : {
            "value" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Run   |     Time |       Hits
1     |     91ms |    4998613
2     |     45ms |    4998613
3     |     46ms |    4998613
4     |     45ms |    4998613
5     |     45ms |    4998613
```

Query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "booleanFlag" : {
            "value" : false,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Run   |     Time |       Hits
1     |     97ms |    5001387
2     |     45ms |    5001387
3     |     45ms |    5001387
4     |     48ms |    5001387
5     |     45ms |    5001387
```

---

### nullFlag - Exists Query

Query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "exists" : {
                "field" : "nullFlag",
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Run   |     Time |       Hits
1     |     99ms |    4999305
2     |     53ms |    4999305
3     |     53ms |    4999305
4     |     53ms |    4999305
5     |     54ms |    4999305
```

Query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "bool" : {
          "must_not" : [
            {
              "exists" : {
                "field" : "nullFlag",
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Run   |     Time |       Hits
1     |    145ms |    5000695
2     |    107ms |    5000695
3     |    104ms |    5000695
4     |    104ms |    5000695
5     |    107ms |    5000695
```

---

### textFlag - Match Query

Query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "match" : {
          "textFlag" : {
            "query" : "VALID",
            "operator" : "OR",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Run   |     Time |       Hits
1     |     87ms |    4998937
2     |     43ms |    4998937
3     |     44ms |    4998937
4     |     43ms |    4998937
5     |     42ms |    4998937
```

Query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "match" : {
          "textFlag" : {
            "query" : "INVALID",
            "operator" : "OR",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Run   |     Time |       Hits
1     |     89ms |    5001063
2     |     48ms |    5001063
3     |     43ms |    5001063
4     |     43ms |    5001063
5     |     43ms |    5001063
```

---

## ----- Tests with multiple flags ------

### textFlag - Match Query with 2 flags

Query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "match" : {
          "textFlag" : {
            "query" : "VALID DUMMY_FLAG1",
            "operator" : "OR",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Run   |     Time |       Hits
1     |    151ms |   10000000
2     |    105ms |   10000000
3     |    106ms |   10000000
4     |    105ms |   10000000
5     |    107ms |   10000000
```

---

### booleanFlag - Term Query with 2 flags

Query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "booleanFlagOne" : {
            "value" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "term" : {
          "booleanFlagTwo" : {
            "value" : false,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Run   |     Time |       Hits
1     |    138ms |    2500645
2     |     84ms |    2500645
3     |     84ms |    2500645
4     |     83ms |    2500645
5     |     86ms |    2500645
```

---

## ----- more tests ------

### nullFlag - Exists Query (without unnecessary double bool query)

Query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "exists" : {
          "field" : "nullFlag",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Run   |     Time |       Hits
1     |     93ms |    5000779
2     |     42ms |    5000779
3     |     43ms |    5000779
4     |     42ms |    5000779
5     |     44ms |    5000779
```

---

Query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "exists" : {
          "field" : "nullFlag",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Run   |     Time |       Hits
1     |     88ms |    5000779
2     |     43ms |    5000779
3     |     42ms |    5000779
4     |     43ms |    5000779
5     |     42ms |    5000779
```

---

Query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must_not" : [
      {
        "exists" : {
          "field" : "nullFlag",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Run   |     Time |       Hits
1     |    139ms |    4999221
2     |     96ms |    4999221
3     |     98ms |    4999221
4     |     95ms |    4999221
5     |     94ms |    4999221
```

Comment: Nice work. If you still have some time to test, I would be interested what happens to the second option (exists query) if you would omit the unnecessary second bool queries. Just bool -> filter -> exist for the first and bool -> must_not -> exist for the second should actually be enough.

Comment: @Slomo cool, that makes the query faster. See "more tests". Thanks for the suggestion. The Java API seems not to provide a "negated filter", i.e. "get everything where the field is empty", so I could't test that.